# Is there a way to speed up nested for loop in C/C++?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

I have the following piece of code which scans a 3-D structure `histMem` where each of the 64x64 elements contains an array of 65536 elements representing a histogram.
The goal is to find the location of the histogram bin with the highest counts.

```
            int maxVal, maxLoc;
            for (int r = 0; r < 64; r++) { //scan over 64 rows
                for (int c = 0; c < 64; c++) { //scan over 64 columns
                    maxVal = histMem[r][c][0];
                    maxLoc = 0;
                    for (int p = 0; p < nBins; p++) { //scan over 65536 histogram bins
                        if (histMem[r][c][p]> maxVal) { //update the max location and max value if needed
                            maxVal = histMem[r][c][p];
                            maxLoc = p;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The variable `histMem` has been declared in such a way:

```
unsigned int*** histMem;
```

and the memory allocation is done using the following function:

```
histMem = createArrayMem(64,64,65536);
```

Specifically, this is what the function `createArrayMem` does:

```
unsigned int*** createArrayMem(int hSize, int vSize, int depth) {

    unsigned int*** arrayMem = new unsigned int** [hSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < hSize; i++) {
        // Allocate memory blocks for rows of each 2D array
        arrayMem[i] = new unsigned int* [vSize];
        for (int j = 0; j < vSize; j++) {
            // Allocate memory blocks for columns of each 2D array
            arrayMem[i][j] = new unsigned int[depth];
        }
    }

    return arrayMem;
}
```

Now the problem is that finding the histogram peak for each of the 64x64 arrays of `histMem` is extremely slow, it takes around 500 milliseconds to do the task.

Is there a way to make this simple operation faster?

Thank you all.

Comment: Yes. Buy better computer and run your program on that.

Comment: `64,64,65536` is the count always the same? Could it be a dynamically allocated single variable with `unsigned int histMem[64][64][65536];`? | Your code resets `maxLoc = 0;` each loop. Why is that variable there at all?

Comment: if you want to find the maximum value among 64x64x65536 values you must visit all elements, no matter how they are arranged, whether it is 3d or a flat 1d array

Comment: General advice: Introduce parallel computation. (OpenMP is easy to use) Use standard functions (like [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)).

Comment: What is the goal of optimization (the expected time to take)? How is the query used? (Are update of the arrays and taking maximum repeated after each other? Taking maximum happens only once after update?)

Comment: who is populating the histograms? If you used a custom type instead of a naked array for the histograms you could keep track of the maximum bin already while filling the histograms

Comment: I need to find the maximum bin for each histogram, so at the end I will have 64x64 maximum bin values.

Comment: The expected time to take has to be way shorter, let's say around 1-2 milliseconds.......

Comment: The little piece of code will be part of a bigger project in which, at the end, a video has to be displayed. So at least 15 frames per seconds are needed.

Comment: Considering also other operation, this is why I can not afford 500 ms for this step

Comment: The histogram is populated by data read-out from a sensor

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are asking for is not realistic.

Your entire data structure is ~ 1GB. Scanning the entire thing 15 times per second requires 15GB/s memory bandwidth. This is on the upper end of what DDR3 supports, and well into mid-range territory for DDR4.

Furthermore, to achieve your stated goal of completing in 1-2 ms, you need to read that much data in that amount of time. Does your computer have a 1TB/s or 500GB/s memory bus?

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can try with [parallel_for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/how-to-write-a-parallel-for-loop?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160)

Comment: could you provide the adaptation to my code?

Comment: Nested Loops are the ones that take time try surrounding them  with     parallel_for (size_t(0), Size, [&](size_t i)